# .accde extensions couldn't be downloaded

Tags: internet-explorer, ms-access, internet-explorer-11

I have trouble finding solutions to get rid of this irritating error whenever I opened MS access application through putting it on a link in Internet Explorer 11.
I have been researching for some ways on how to solve this issue. To no avail, I don't find one.
Can somebody give me some ways that MS access files can be opened in IE11?

Thanks a lot for help.

[image]

Comment: is your computer part of an AD? you might have group policy preventing harmful files to be downloaded. Usually web-server will not allow certain extensions to be accessed. Yours looks like local/group policy issue.

Comment: Yes, my pc is part of AD but this error only happens when there's an upgrade in IE from 8 to 11. In IE 8, the file can be open directly but in IE 11, the above error will show.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue in my environment.  I was able to track the problem to links that use a relative file path like file://server/share/filename.  I corrected the behavior by changing the links so they reference the FQDN of the server like file://server.domain.com/share/filename.  The link will be correctly identified as in the Intranet Zone and the file will open.

Comment: still the same issue.